# Error: Using the URLconf defined in helloapp.urls, can't figure out solution

Tags: python, django, terminal

There was a question similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694110/error-using-the-urlconf-defined-in-mysite-urls-django-tried-these-url-patterns)
but I couldn't exactly find my soltution from that. Plus I want to understand how to solve this and not just get solution haha. Please let me know if I should rephrase or include anything else! 
I am following [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-your-first-python-and-django-application#setting-up)
tutorial and I have reached the part where I need to runserver. But it pops up with an error and I'm not sure what to do next to solve this. Error page saying:

"Using the URLconf defined in helloapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
, ^helloapp/

The empty path didn't match any of these."

My project is as follows helloapp: hello app, howdy

helloapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
  path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^helloapp/', include('howdy.urls')),
]
```

howdy/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# howdy/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

#Create your views here

class HomePageView(TemplateView):

def get(self, request, **kwargs):

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=None)
```

howdy/templates/index.html

```
<!-- howdy/templates/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Howdy!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Howdy! I am Learning Django!</h1>
</body>
```

howdy/urls.py

```
#howdy/urls.py


from django.conf.urls import url

from howdy import views

urlpatterns = [ 

   url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),

]
```

Comment: At which URL are you getting the error? As far as i can tell, you have no root url defined, so `localhost:8080` (assuming default local runserver) can not resolve to anything - only `localhost:8080/helloapp` (resolves to HomePageView) and `localhost:8080/admin/` (resolves all the URLs within `django.contrib.admin.site.urls` will work

Comment: @wiesion heres a c&p from the terminal "System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 09, 2018 - 21:34:56
Django version 2.0.6, using settings 'helloapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /
[09/Jun/2018 21:35:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2033 "

Comment: `Not Found: /` means you are trying to open the root page, which has no match in urlpatterns

Comment: try to open 127.0.0.1:8000/helloapp - it should show your HomePageView correctly - but there is no urlpattern for 127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: @wiesion that works! do i need to set a urlpattern for 127.0.0.1:8000/ ? sorry if this is a dumb question, i'm very new to this!

Comment: There's different things you can do, either redirect `^$` to /helloapp or point `^$` to HomePageView

Comment: The answers here may be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580220/django-urls-howto-map-root-to-app

Comment: @wiesion oh hell yeah! i think i've resolved it now. no errors have returned. thank you so much!!

Comment: yw and enjoy django :)